# jquery has two contents in $.(one,two).html();

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know what to call them, I usually only encounter single `$.(one).html()` but not `$.(one,two).html();` in jQuery.

```
var handler = function(data) {
    $('.content').html($('.content', data).html()).parent().show();
    $.address.title(/>([^<]*)<\/title/.exec(data)[1]);
};
```

Can you guys please *help* me understand what this code does? I've never encountered such code. These are the specific parts that I cannot understand, How do these lines work?

```
$('.content', data).html();

$.address.title(/>([^<]*)<\/title/.exec(data)[1]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.content', data).html();
```

This is looking for an element with the class `content` within the `data` variable. This is known as a contextual selector. The `data` variable can be a string, a DOM element or jQuery object.

For example:

```
var data = '<div><p class="content">Lorem ipsum</p></div>';
var html = $('.content', data).html(); // = 'Lorem ipsum'
```

The `html` variable will then always contain `Lorem ipsum` no matter how many other `.content` elements are within your page.

---

```
$.address.title(/>([^<]*)<\/title/.exec(data)[1]);
```

This is performing a regular expression on the `data` variable. It is the inverse method of `data.match(/>([^<]*)<\/title/);`

It will return an array containing each match, or null if none are found.

Comment: But when you try removing the `div` the value of `var html` is `null`. Why is it so?

Answer (score 3):

The first is a [selector, and a context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/). It's searching for `.content` within `data`. jQuery then returns jQuery objects which have the `.html()` method.

The second is a [regex pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). It's using the `/>([^<]*)<\/title/` regex to search `data` probably to find the contents of the `title` tag.

Comment: so what does `$('.content', data).html()` do considering that data is just some random text?

Comment: The selector is **not** a multiple - look at the positions of the quotes. It's providing `data` as a context: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for picking up on that, didn't notice it!

Comment: Ah that explains it. Thank you @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @djlumley could u check my comment at Rory's answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a regular expression, it checks for a pattern.

([^<]*) means "everything from the <".

Basically, it searchs in a string what starts with `<title>` and ends with `</title>`, and use it.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument for $ function is just a context. It says jQuery to look for the element inside that context element.
Below expressions are equal in there behavior. I hope this will clarify what is for the second argument.

```
$(one,two).html(); = $(two).filter(one).html();
```